# There was an error while installing node modules using npm install in react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm-install

There was an error while installing node modules using`npm install`
I have xcode and command line tools installed but the build still failed.

I am adding a node module to a project of mine and I am not able to build the project till I do an npm install delete the node modules folder and do an npm install again. Just deleting the node modules and doing an npm install does not fix it.

Here's the error output :

```
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:72:
../src/thread.cc:36:25: error: unknown type name 'ConstFSEventStreamRef'
void HandleStreamEvents(ConstFSEventStreamRef stream, void *ctx, size_t ...
                        ^
../src/thread.cc:36:108: error: unknown type name 'FSEventStreamEventFlags'
  ...stream, void *ctx, size_t numEvents, void *eventPaths, const FSEventStre...
                                                                  ^
../src/thread.cc:36:152: error: unknown type name 'FSEventStreamEventId'
  ...*eventPaths, const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[], const FSEventSt...
                                                                    ^
../src/thread.cc:54:3: error: unknown type name 'FSEventStreamContext'
  FSEventStreamContext context = { 0, ctx, NULL, NULL, NULL };
  ^
../src/thread.cc:56:3: error: unknown type name 'FSEventStreamRef'
  FSEventStreamRef stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL, &HandleStreamEvent...
  ^
../src/thread.cc:56:98: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow'
  ...&HandleStreamEvents, &context, fse->paths, kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow...
                                                ^
6 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/macos/Desktop/baps_yuva/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this one

```
brew update

brew install watchman

npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall / reinstall npm:

- sudo npm uninstall npm -g
- brew install npm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,for me I solved it by downgrading npm version

npm install -g npm@5.6.0